# How to add image in pdf file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation

I have used [this](http://www.semanticarchitecture.net/www/pdf-reporting-using-asp-net-mvc/) blog for adding a dynamic pdf in my project. when i am tryng to add a image than it is compelling me to have a Image folder in C:\ . How can i add a image from project.

Comment: You may want the title to reflect something like "how do I put an image in a PDF document using iTextSharp?" because the way to do this varies based on what you are using for PDF generation and it would clarify the real question.

Comment: @JaredPeless Ohk !!! I will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be using a html view page to render the PDF so you can just use a normal `img` tag like you would in any html page.

With razor syntax you can do something like this:

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/mypic.png")" />
```

---

I believe [this may solve your issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1596224.aspx/1). Essentially you want to specify the full web url as the `src` of the `img`, for example:

```
<img alt="" src="www.example.com/images/mypic.png" />
```

Comment: @SonamMohite: And does the path exist? what happens if you just view the page (without the pdf generation)? do you see the image then?

Comment: Ya without pdf generation , i am able to see the page with image. The problem is that, this wants image path in C drive only.....    Can't i change path ????  :(

Comment: YOu cannot change to C:/ because you browser cannot access the harddrive of a client machine

Comment: So... Is there any idea how to do this..??

Comment: You will need to likely embed the image content the HTML to do this (just a hunch), or find documentation strictly on using HTML to generate a PDF with images using iTextSharp.  I don't know that PDFs can include externally referenced content, and using the syntax you are for doing the @Url.Content() means you are getting a reference only, so when it is created as a PDF I doubt that will ever work with a HTTP reference or relative reference due to limitations in iTextSharp resolving the file to embed in the PDF.